# Get the currently selected range from RangeSelector in Highstock

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using both highcharts and highstock and have some charts that use the `rangeSelector`.

Everything's working fine, but I'd like to GET the currently selected range (when the user clicks one of the `rangeSelector` buttons), so that I can store it in a cookie to know which range I want to display by default next time.

I've tried various things so far, like adding a `chart.events.redraw` test to try and catch the `chart.rangeSelector.buttons` object, but it doesn't seem to contain anything interesting in my case.

To me, the ideal would be an event callback on the rangeselector.buttons, with a simple getter function, like the equivalent of the `chart.rangeSelector.buttons[x].setState()`, named `chart.rangeSelector.buttons[x].getState()` ?

I'm surprised this doesn't exist... I must be missing something. Anybody can help on that ?

Comment: post what you have tried or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Take look at the related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846859/which-rangeselector-button-is-selected-in-highcharts

Comment: The jsfiddle from http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/1/ seems to answer the question partially (though I'm still surprised there is no event callback for this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jsfiddle from [jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/1](http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/1) seems to answer the question partially (though I'm still surprised there is no event callback for this)

The setExtremes event on the xaxis does the job:

```
 xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {
                console.log(this);
                if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined')
                {
                  alert('count: '+e.rangeSelectorButton.count + 'text: ' +e.rangeSelectorButton.text + ' type:' + e.rangeSelectorButton.type);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/5/ should do what you want:

```
xAxis: {
  events: {
    setExtremes: function(e) {
      if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined') {
        var c = e.rangeSelectorButton.count;
        var t = e.rangeSelectorButton.type;
        var btn_index = null;
        if(c == 1 && t == "month"){
          btn_index = 0;
        } else if(c == 3 && t == "month"){
          btn_index = 1;
        } else if(c == 6 && t == "month"){
          btn_index = 2;
        } else if(t == "ytd"){
          btn_index = 3;
        } else if(c == 1 && t == "year"){
          btn_index = 4;
        } else if(t == "all"){
          btn_index = 5;
        }
        // Store btn_index in a cookie here and use it
        // to initialise rangeSelector -> selected next
        // time the chart is loaded
        alert(btn_index);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

chart event: redraw can get the display range. Code is tested in highstock 3.10

```
events: {
    redraw: function(event) {
        console.log('==============> chart redraw <==============');
        console.log(
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event.currentTarget.xAxis[0].min),
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event.currentTarget.xAxis[0].max)
        );
        // log the min and max of the y axis
        console.log(event.currentTarget.yAxis[0].min, event.currentTarget.yAxis[0].max);
    }
}
```