# Set a custom rangeSelector and disable xAxis label on chart and on Navigator with Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm using highstock with lazy-loading like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/), i'm using 2 different series: both have a "time" parameter but none of them should have a date-time xAxis.

Each series has a structure like this:

```
serie1:[{"x" => 1, "y" => value_1, "time" => time_of_point_1},
        {"x" => 2, "y" => value_2, "time" => time_of_point_2},
        ....
        {"x" => n, "y" => value_n, "time" => time_of_point_n}];


serie2:[{"x" => 1, "y" => value_1, "z" => value_z_1, "time" => time_of_point_1},
        {"x" => 2, "y" => value_2, "z" => value_z_2, "time" => time_of_point_2},
        ....
        {"x" => n, "y" => value_n, "z" => value_z_n, "time" => time_of_point_n}];
```

My goal it to have a custom rangeSelector that zoom the chart according to the time parameter that each point has.

So my questions are:

**Is possible to have a custom rangeSelector that zoom on chart according to a point parameter different from x and y values?:**

let's say:

```
 events:{
    if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" && 
        e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "last 3 hours"){
        // zoom on chart and set the chart
        // with all point that has "time" parameter 
        // between now and the last three hours
    }
}
```

**Than I'm looking to a way to disable X Axis label to make all more readable.**

I'm trying to disable the label on chart xAxis and on Navigator xAxis too but no matter what it shows up every time.

I used this code on both:

```
xAxis : {
    label: {
       enabled: false
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways:

- you can call rangeselector click and call
  [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)
  [rel
  topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846859/which-rangeselector-button-is-selected-in-highcharts)
- prepare your own html buttons and call setExtremes()

In the xAxis it should be labels, instaed of label:

```
xAxis : {
    labels: {
       enabled: false
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding the xAxis label it was a typo, thanks for it!! regarding the  range selector, your second suggestion is to create some html button, that call my ajax funtion to retrieve the series between my limits and pass to the chart the extremes? is it right??
I don't really understand the first way you suggest

Comment: I would like to use the standard range selector (e.g. "15m", "1h", "3h", "ALL") but with a custom behavior seen that my x-axis is not based on time.

Comment: Have you a demo of it?