# Highstock Trigger javascript when range selector button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How would I get, say, an `alert("Don't touch me!")` to execute when I press the  '2Week' button in the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/610335vt/

Comment: Maybe this post can helpyou.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846859/which-rangeselector-button-is-selected-in-highcharts

Comment: But how would I make that event based?

Comment: I don't know library, so I did a research and I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/donli/747U5/ and 
http://jsfiddle.net/donli/W5gYy/


on official forum.

http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/highstock-range-selector-click-event-t20632/

Try to search in this forum thread

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stepday/LSdrX/ this is fiddle that can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the setExtremes event, check `e.rangeSelectorButton.text` and find a current button. Then call custom action.

```
   xAxis: {
     events: {
       setExtremes: function(e) {
        if (e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "2Weeks") {
           alert('a');
         }
       }
     }
   },
```

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/ze6qdc1u/

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
In fiddle that I found, there is a prototype like this.

```
$(function () {
            //buttons
            (function (H) {
                //rangeSelector buttons
                var A = H.Chart;
                var options = H.getOptions();
                p = H.extend;
                k = H.merge;
                p(A.prototype, {
                    bindEvents: function (b, c) {
                        if (c.click) {
                            b.on("click", c.click);
                        }
                    }
                });
                //rangeSelector events
                A.prototype.callbacks.push(function (b) {
                    //                 
                    var c = b.rangeSelector.buttons, d = b.options.rangeSelector;
                    if (c && d) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                            b.bindEvents(c[i], d);
                        }
                    }
                });
            })(Highcharts);
```

Try use this

```
rangeSelector: {
                click: function () {
                    alert("test");
                },
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 5,
                    text: '5y',
                    click: function () {
                        alert("test");
                    }
                }
}
```

I found in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stepday/LSdrX/ I haven't tested in my local, but you can try with example code in fiddle

Comment: hmmm... I can't seem to get it working. There's nothing about click in the API documentation for what it's worth... http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.enabled

Comment: Yeah, I see, infact in fiddle that I proposed to you there is prototype, sorry my answer is incomplete. I edit.

Comment: Thanks, I can see it working in the example but I'm not sure which part is relevant.

Comment: button haven't click event, infact you have to do a prototype that wich allow to do this